# Network connectivity with VPN on Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, vpn

I want to be able to connect to my private domains remotely. To that end, I've set up a VPN server on my Windows 10 machine. However, once I'm connected, the server and client can't communicate with each other. They can ping themselves with their own VPN IP addresses, but not each other.

The VPN server's Network Connections window shows that a connection has successfully been made.

How can I get network traffic between the VPN server and client(s)?

Comment: What software is running the server? It's sometimes called client isolation in some server software.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Just Microsoft's built-in VPN server.

Comment: Active firewalls on any of the clients? Disable them for troubleshooting.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Same results with firewalls on or off.